# How can I stop Xorg from loading the nvidia modules (aka to stop using my GPU)?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, gpu-passthrough

I have a triple-monitor setup. The two main monitors are connected to the integrated GPU (Intel UHD), and the third one is connected to an nvidia GTX 1060 card.

In the BIOS, I have the iGPU set as the default, and my OS, Manjaro loads on this GPU. I have disabled the third GPU in the display settings, because I only want to use the iGPU and the two monitors connected to it for linux. The dedicated GPU and the third monitor will be passed to a Windows 10 VM whenever it's running.

The reason why I want to stop Xorg from using my GPU is because with my current setup, I have to shut down my display manager in order to be able to unload the nvidia kernel modules and start the VM with the GPU passed to it via VFIO. This means that I have to close all graphical programs which is very inconvenient.

I'd like to be able to run the VM on the third monitor without having to stop the display manager, so I can use linux and windows at the same time. To me this makes sense, because right now the DM is running on the integrated GPU and not the 1060, so I feel like I should be able to disable the card and pass it to the VM without having to kill the host DM.

Running the following command reveals that nvidia is still being used by Xorg, even after I've disabled the third monitor in the display settings.

```
# ps -p `lsof -t /dev/nvidia*` -o comm=;
```

I'm running manjaro with the `video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-455xx-prime`, `video-vesa` and `video-modesetting` drivers installed.

I'd like to note that I still want to be able to use PRIME offloading on the linux host (`prime-run`) whenever the VM is not running.

Comment: Why do you need to have NVIDIA drivers installed at all then? You seemingly don't need them at all.

Comment: Because I also need the nvidia PRIME render offloading on the linux host when the VM isn't running. I only need the VM for a very few windows-exclusive programs and games, but I also want to make use of the 1060 on the linux host whenever I can.

Comment: Deleting `/usr/lib[64]/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so` could be enough.

Comment: I'm getting close. I was able to run Windows and SDDM simultaneously after deleting the driver file, but now I'm unable to use prime-run

Comment: It seems to me you can either have this driver and are able to run prime-run or you run your guest OS.